# Why does't my additionalChoices constructor get called?

Tags: java

This is the instruction of the project I am working on.

[image: instructions]

Now I am only working on the basic hamburger class.

The question becomes :  why doesn't my additionalChoice constructor get called ? it does not increase the total price so that is how I figured it does not get called. What could be the problem?

Note: If you have any suggestions in regards to better approaching this project and better writing this program, please write it down I would very much appreciate it.

My code:

```
class Burger {

    private String name;
    private String meatType;
    private String breadType;

    private double totalPrice = 0;
    private String addition1;

    public Burger(String name, String meatType, String breadType) {
        System.out.println("Your name is " + name);
        this.name = name;
        this.meatType = meatType;
        meatChoice(meatType);
        this.breadType = breadType;
        breadChoice(breadType);
    }


    public double getTotalPrice() {
        System.out.println("You need to pay : " +  totalPrice);
        return totalPrice;
    }

    public double meatChoice( String meatType) {
            if (meatType == "chicken") {
                System.out.println("You have selected Chicken");
                totalPrice += 3;
            } else if (meatType == "beef") {
                System.out.println("You have selected Beef");
                totalPrice += 3;
            } else if (meatType == "ham") {
                System.out.println("You have selected Ham");
                totalPrice += 3;
            } else {
                System.out.println("We do not have the meat selected, please try again");
                totalPrice += 0;
            }        return totalPrice;

    }

    public double breadChoice(String breadType) {
        if (breadType == "french") {
            System.out.println("You have selected french bread");
            totalPrice += 2;
        } else if (breadType == "persian") {
            System.out.println("You have selected persian bread");
            totalPrice += 2;
        }
        return totalPrice;
    }

    public double additionalChoices(String addition1){
        while (addition1=="done") {
            switch (addition1) {
                case "tomato":
                    System.out.println("You have selected Tomato for your topping. If you are done type in 'done'");
                    totalPrice += 2;
                    break;
                case "lettuce":
                    System.out.println("You have selected lettuce for your topping.If you are done type in 'done'");
                    totalPrice += 2;
                    break;
                case "onion":
                    System.out.println("You have selected onion for your topping.If you are done type in 'done'");
                    totalPrice += 2;
                    break;
                case "olive":
                    System.out.println("You have selected olive for your topping.If you are done type in 'done'");
                    totalPrice += 2;
                    break;
                case "done":
                    System.out.println("Thank you for your oder");
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid input");
            }

        } return totalPrice;


}
}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Burger basicBurger = new Burger("mehr","beef","french");
        basicBurger.additionalChoices("tomato");
        basicBurger.additionalChoices("olive");
        basicBurger.getTotalPrice();


    }

}
```

Comment: what is your expectation by saying *This is the instruction of the project I am working on.* You need to stick to what you have done so far and what is your problem.

Comment: ALL of your string comparisons are incorrect. You use `==` when you should be using `.equals()`

Comment: @Ravi I wanted to be clear on what I am asking why so much hate??????

Comment: @Mehrs. lol, First of all, post image instead of typing them is not acceptable here, second simply saying *This is the instruction of the project I am working on.* instead summarize, what are you looking for, what have you tried and what is blocking you. The way you posted your question looks like you are posting a requirement to fulfill.

Comment: @Mehrs. read these https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Remember, your post may help other later point of time, so your question and title shouldn't be specific to your project else it will be hard to find for other.

Comment: @Mehrs. if you understand, then you need to remove your previous comment.

Comment: @Ravi I don't want to ! U can't tell me what to do

Comment: @Mehrs. seriously, you are making me laugh :D it's your choice of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while-loop inside `additionalChoices(String addition1)` method is broken. Firstly, you don't compare Strings in Java with `==` operator, but using `.equals()` method, e.g.

```
addition1.equals("done")
```

or even

```
"done".equals(addition1)
```

which is even better, because it wont throw `NullPointerException` if `addition1` is `null`.

Secondly, your while-loop does not make much sense. You will get inside its block only if you pass `"done"` parameter, which does not seem logic. But if you negate condition to `while (!"done".equals(addition1))` which translates to "do as long as `addition1` is not `"done"`, then you will run into infinite loop while calling e.g.

```
basicBurger.additionalChoices("tomato");
```

It looks like in this case you don't really need any while-loop. At least not the one you have shown us, which is completely broken.

Answer (score 0):

You have an unnecessary `while` loop. Remove

```
 while (addition1=="done") {
```

And the corresponding `}` .

Code never enter the while

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line and it closing bracket:

```
while (addition1=="done") {
```

I don't now why is there but you will never enter in the `switch` statement, unless you pass `done` like argument.

Comment: Isn't is the same answer as mine?